# Remove element from array inside array of objects if present in another array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, object

I am working with a large array of objects. I have simplified my data structure to the following. Each object has an `id` and each `id` has two arrays associated with it `type1` and `type2`.

```
const arr = [{id: "12345", type1: ["Hat 1", "Hat 3"], type2: ["Hat 2", "Glove 4"]}, 
             {id: "12345", type1: ["Glove 1", "Hat 1"], type2: ["Glove 3", "Hat 2"]},           
             {id: "54321", type1: ["Jacket 1", "Hat 4"], type2: ["Hat 3", "Hat 4"]},
             {id: "54321", type1: ["Glove 2", "Hat 2"], type2: ["Glove 3", "Jacket 4"]},
             {id: "13579", type1: ["Hat 1", "Hat 2"], type2: ["Hat 3", "Hat 4"]},
             {id: "13579", type1: ["Glove 1", "Glove 2"], type2: ["Glove 3", "Glove 4"]}]
```

I have a "lookup" array of objects. Each object has an `id` and a `title`

```
const lookup = [{id: "12345", title: "Hat 1"},
                {id: "12345", title: "Hat 2"},
                {id: "12345", title: "Glove 3"},
                {id: "54321", title: "Hat 3"} 
                {id: "54321", title: "Jacket 4"},
                {id: "54321", title: "Glove 5"},
                {id: "13579", title: "Hat 2"},
                {id: "13579", title: "Jacket 3"}]
```

I need to use the "lookup" object for any matching id that has a `title` I need to remove it from type1 or type2 or both. So my resulting array of objects would look something like so

```
const result = [{id: "12345", type1: ["Hat 3"], type2: ["Glove 4"]}, 
                {id: "12345", type1: ["Glove 1"], type2: []},           
                {id: "54321", type1: ["Jacket 1", "Hat 4"], type2: ["Hat 4"]},
                {id: "54321", type1: ["Glove 2", "Hat 2"], type2: ["Glove 3"]},
                {id: "13579", type1: ["Hat 1"], type2: ["Hat 3", "Hat 4"]},
                {id: "13579", type1: ["Glove 1", "Glove 2"], type2: ["Glove 3", "Glove 4"]}]
```

The duplicates and having to search through both arrays for any matching id's is confusing me. Is there a simple way to do this or maybe a better way to structure the data so it's not so convoluted?

Comment: Have you made any attempt at all to come up with such a result yourself yet? Please post the code you've tried

Comment: should the lookup happen 1:1 i.e. lookup first obj of arr with first obj of lookup? The result array looks a bit confusing. Lookup key 12345 contains titles hat 1, hat 2 and glove 3. In that case the second object(id=12345) in result object should not contain hat 1 in type1 and hat 2 in type 2.

Comment: @SubSul That was my mistake. Oversight on my part when i was simplifying the data structure

Comment: Depending on how much control you have over the structure of the lookup data, it would simplify things to structure the "lookup" data as json with key "id" and value as array of all titles for that id like `{"12345": ["Hat 1", "Hat 2", "Glove 3"]}`. Then you could just loop through the "arr" data, access the lookup key that corresponds to the id and remove any matching types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through `arr` and for each entry of `arr`, loop through `lookup` to compare and modify `arr`

```
  for(let arrEntry of arr) {
    let id = arrEntry.id;
    let type1 = arrEntry.type1;
    let type2 = arrEntry.type2;

    for(let lookupEntry of lookup) {
      let title = lookupEntry.title;
      if(lookupEntry.id === id && type1.includes(title)) {
        type1.splice(type1.indexOf(title), 1);
      }
      if(lookupEntry.id === id && type2.includes(title)) {
        type2.splice(type2.indexOf(title), 1);
      }
    }
  }

  console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's not mutate the original data, and create a new resultant array. you can use `map`, `filter` and `some` of `Array`

```
arr.map(({id, type1, type2}) => ({
    id,
    type1: type1.filter(t => !lookup.some(l => id===l.id && l.title === t)),
    type2: type2.filter(t => !lookup.some(l => id===l.id && l.title === t))
}));
```

Here is an working example:

```js
const arr =[
     {id: "12345", type1: ["Hat 1", "Hat 3"], type2: ["Hat 2", "Glove 4"]}, 
     {id: "12345", type1: ["Glove 1", "Hat 1"], type2: ["Glove 3", "Hat 2"]},           
     {id: "54321", type1: ["Jacket 1", "Hat 4"], type2: ["Hat 3", "Hat 4"]},
     {id: "54321", type1: ["Glove 2", "Hat 2"], type2: ["Glove 3", "Jacket 4"]},
     {id: "13579", type1: ["Hat 1", "Hat 2"], type2: ["Hat 3", "Hat 4"]},
     {id: "13579", type1: ["Glove 1", "Glove 2"], type2: ["Glove 3", "Glove 4"]}
  ],
  lookup = [
     {id: "12345", title: "Hat 1"},
     {id: "12345", title: "Hat 2"},
     {id: "12345", title: "Glove 3"},
     {id: "54321", title: "Hat 3"}, 
     {id: "54321", title: "Jacket 4"},
     {id: "54321", title: "Glove 5"},
     {id: "13579", title: "Hat 2"},
     {id: "13579", title: "Jacket 3"}
  ],
  res = arr.map(({id, type1, type2}) => ({
   id,
   type1: type1.filter(t => !lookup.some(l => id===l.id && l.title === t)),
   type2: type2.filter(t => !lookup.some(l => id===l.id && l.title === t))
  }));
  
  console.log(res);
```